# Is there way to build no of listener for a queue by using configuration file in AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have published 50K objects to a specific queue. I have one listener which picks each object and process that. But obviously it will take more time to process all 50k objects. So i want to place 3 more listeners which can parallel process those objects. For this purpose am i need to write two more listener classes? with same code? that will be duplicate of code. Is there any approach we can configure number of listeners we want, so that internally it will create instances for same listener to handle the load?Can any one help me the better way to stand 3 more listeners to handle the load to increase processing.

====Rabbit mq configuration file piece of code=============

```
@Bean
    public SubscriberGeneralQueue1 SubscriberGeneralQueue1(){
        return new SubscriberGeneralQueue1();
    }

@Bean
        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer rpcGeneralReplyMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter1 ) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(replyQueueRPC());
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter1);
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(60);
            return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
        }
       @Bean
        @Qualifier("listenerAdapter1")
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter1(SubscriberGeneralQueue1 generalReceiver) {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(generalReceiver, "receivegeneralQueueMessage");
        }
```

===Listener code================

```
@EnableRabbit
public class SubscriberGeneralQueue1 {

     /*@Autowired
        @Qualifier("asyncGeneralRabbitTemplate")
    private AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncGeneralRabbitTemplate;*/

    @Autowired
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    @Autowired
    private GeneralProcess generalProcess;

    List <RequestPojo> requestPojoGeneral = new ArrayList<RequestPojo>();

    @RabbitHandler
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory", queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")
    public void subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload RequestPojo sampleRequestMessage, Message message) throws InterruptedException {

        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

        //requestPojoGeneral.add(sampleRequestMessage);
        //System.out.println("List size issssss:" +requestPojoGeneral.size() );
        //generalProcess.processRequestObjectslist(requestPojoGeneral);
        generalProcess.processRequestObjects(sampleRequestMessage);

        System.out.println("message in general listener is:" + sampleRequestMessage.getDistance());
        System.out.println("Message payload is:" + sampleRequestMessage);
        System.out.println("Message payload1111 is:" + message );

        //return requestPojoGeneral;

    }
```

}

===simplemessagelistenercontainerFactory configuration===========

```
 @Bean
        public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                                          SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
            factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(60);
            configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
            return factory;
        }
```

====Suggested changes=====

```
@RabbitHandler
    @Async
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory", queues ="BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue")
    public void subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload RequestPojo sampleRequestMessage, Message message) throws InterruptedException {

        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

        //requestPojoGeneral.add(sampleRequestMessage);
        //System.out.println("List size issssss:" +requestPojoGeneral.size() );
        //generalProcess.processRequestObjectslist(requestPojoGeneral);
        generalProcess.processRequestObjects(sampleRequestMessage);

        System.out.println("message in general listener is:" + sampleRequestMessage.getDistance());
        System.out.println("Message payload is:" + sampleRequestMessage);
        System.out.println("Message payload1111 is:" + message );

        //return requestPojoGeneral;

    }


}
```

configuration:

```
@Bean
        public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                                          SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
            factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(60);
            factory.setConsecutiveActiveTrigger(1);
            configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
            return factory;
        }

  @Bean
        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer rpcGeneralReplyMessageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter1 ) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(replyQueueRPC());
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter1);
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(100);
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setConsecutiveActiveTrigger(1);
            return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's can be done with the `concurrency` option of the `ListenerContainer`:

> Threads from the `TaskExecutor` configured in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` are used to invoke the `MessageListener` when a new message is delivered by RabbitMQ Client. If not configured, a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is used. If a pooled executor is used, ensure the pool size is sufficient to handle the configured concurrency. With the `DirectMessageListenerContainer`, the `MessageListener` is invoked directly on a RabbitMQ Client thread. In this case, the `taskExecutor` is used for the task that monitors the consumers.

Please, start reading from here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/_reference.html#receiving-messages

And also see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/_reference.html#containerAttributes

> concurrentConsumers (concurrency) - The number of concurrent consumers to initially start for each listener.

**UPDATE**

Alright! I see what's going on.

We have there a code like this:

```
 boolean receivedOk = receiveAndExecute(this.consumer); // At least one message received
                    if (SimpleMessageListenerContainer.this.maxConcurrentConsumers != null) {
                        if (receivedOk) {
                            if (isActive(this.consumer)) {
                                consecutiveIdles = 0;
                                if (consecutiveMessages++ > SimpleMessageListenerContainer.this.consecutiveActiveTrigger) {
                                    considerAddingAConsumer();
                                    consecutiveMessages = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

so, we check for possible parallelism only after the first message is processed. So, in your case it is going to happen after 1 minute.

Another flag to `considerAddingAConsumer()` is about a `consecutiveActiveTrigger` option with is this by default:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_CONSECUTIVE_ACTIVE_TRIGGER = 10;
```

So, in your case to allow to parallel just exactly the next message you should also configure a :

```
/**
 * If {@link #maxConcurrentConsumers} is greater then {@link #concurrentConsumers}, and
 * {@link #maxConcurrentConsumers} has not been reached, specifies the number of
 * consecutive cycles when a single consumer was active, in order to consider
 * starting a new consumer. If the consumer goes idle for one cycle, the counter is reset.
 * This is impacted by the {@link #txSize}.
 * Default is 10 consecutive messages.
 * @param consecutiveActiveTrigger The number of consecutive receives to trigger a new consumer.
 * @see #setMaxConcurrentConsumers(int)
 * @see #setStartConsumerMinInterval(long)
 * @see #setTxSize(int)
 */
public final void setConsecutiveActiveTrigger(int consecutiveActiveTrigger) {
    Assert.isTrue(consecutiveActiveTrigger > 0, "'consecutiveActiveTrigger' must be > 0");
    this.consecutiveActiveTrigger = consecutiveActiveTrigger;
}
```

to `1`. Because `0` is not going to work anyway.

For better performance you also may consider to make your `subscribeToRequestQueue()` with the `@Async` to really hand off the processing from the consumer thread to some other to avoid that 1 minute to wait for one more consumer to start.

Comment: Thanks Bilan. I try to implement by referring the above documents.

Comment: Hi Bilan edited my thread above to add code. I have added property simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(60); And my listener class is :SubscriberGeneralQueue1 . So depending upon load it will automatically create SubscriberGeneralQueue1 instances to handle load?

Comment: No. It will create tasks to be executed in parallel. Your `SubscriberGeneralQueue1` is still going to be as a single instance. That's all. You should ensure that your listener is *stateless*.

Comment: okay. You mentioned tasks to be executed in parallel : it means will it execute the tasks which i intended to do inside my SubscriberGeneralQueue1 ? Am i all set then to listen and process message objects in parallel? ?

Comment: HI Bilan, I did not see improvement processing /consuming the message objects from the queue to cleanup the queue(that means all was consumed by subscriber class). Here i want achieve load balancing  thing so that my all request objects distributed between subscribers to increase processing speeds.

Comment: You need to consider to modify concurrency for that `simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` which you use for the `@RabbitListener`

Comment: For suppose i have 10 message objects in my queue. Now i am receiving them one after other  from my subscriber and will process them for processing it will take 1 minute, so to complete 10 objects it will take 10 minutes. But what i want is: i have to receive all at a time(like load balancing) so that these will be distributed between subscribers , so at a time i can process 5 objects or may be 10 objects at a time which may decrease 10 minutes time to 3 minutes.

Comment: I have added my simpleMeasseListenerContainerFactory and added setMaxConcurrentConsumers(60). so that can i receive  multiple message objects  at a time for processing them in parallel ?

Comment: Please, see an `UPDATE` in my answer.

Comment: HI Bilan thanks for the information. I have edited my thread and added the updated code. Can you see i did correctly, so that i am able to pick multiple objects at a same time from queue and process in parallel .

Comment: I tested the same. on Rabbit console under unacked section i am seeing some number starting with 4 and keep on increase now t became 20 (it means they are pulled from queue but it seems the subscribers not generated to handle all of them in parallel.  There are no sufficient subscribers created to handle those 20 requests under unacked , the unacked keep on increasing its number.

Comment: I think that's correct, because you said that your process is long enough.

Comment: Now under unacked i am seeing number 43, is it mean 43 subscribers are working in parallel  to process 43 request messages?

Comment: According to your `setMaxConcurrentConsumers(100)` it looks like

Comment: Hi Bilan every thing looks good. But i saw  at start only one message only received by subscriber, it is taking some idle time to pull multiple messages for  processing in parallel . Is there any property to set to do parallel processing from the beginning on wards?

Comment: As I said you in the answer: no, it doesn't work that way out of the box. We start a new consumer only when we finished with the previous message. You can consider to configure a `prefetchCount = 1` do not poll many messages with a single consumer.

Comment: a bit confused Bilan. I think now consumers are working in parallel . For suppose consumer dealing with message1 and other consumer will work in parallel to handle message2 right ?, i think that is the reason i saw messages under unack more than 1  as i configured setMaxConcurrentConsumers(100).

Comment: Please let me know, my understanding is right or not, if not correct me.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work that simple if your listener is blocked. The container will wait until your process the fist message and only after that the decision about concurrency is made. But if you hand off your message in the listener to another thread, then yes: the control comes back to the container pretty fast and your are ready to spawn a new consumer for the next message.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. How to hand off my message in the listener to another thread ? is it by using @Async on top of subscribeToRequestQueue(@Payload RequestPojo sampleRequestMessage, Message message) ?

Comment: Correct. `@Async` does the trick for you. Although you need to keep in mind that the message on queue is going to be ack'ed before you process it.

Comment: Thanks Bilan for your help. I really like rabbit-mq developers the way they are supporting their product and helping the people who are using rabbit-mq. I have one more question regarding performance i will ask that question in separate thread.

Comment: Glad to hear! For a note: my first name is Artem and I'm a Spring developer, not RabbitMQ :-)